# Почему указатель на массив char произвольно изменяется?

Tags: c++, указатели

У меня есть функция, которая возвращает указатель на массив символов. Вот она:

```
char* GetPasport()
{
    while (1>0)
    {
        cout << "Введите паспортные данные: ";
        char pasp[12];
        cin.getline(pasp, 12);
        if (isdigit(pasp[0]) && isdigit(pasp[1]) && isdigit(pasp[2]) && isdigit(pasp[3]) && pasp[4] == '-' &&
            isdigit(pasp[5]) && isdigit(pasp[6]) && isdigit(pasp[7]) && isdigit(pasp[8]) && isdigit(pasp[9]) && isdigit(pasp[10]))
        {
            return pasp;
        }
        else
        {
            cin.clear(); 
            if (size(pasp) ==11)
            {
                cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            }
            cout <<endl<< "Паспортные данные были введены некорректно." << endl;
            cout << "Формат ввода паспортных данных: ****-******" << endl;
        }
    }   
}
```

в функции main() я создаю указатель на массив char и присваиваю его функции GetPasport()

```
char* pasp = new char;
    pasp= GetPasport();
    cout << pasp;
```

При попытке вывода, программа выводит непонятные символы. Пытался прогнать программу через отладчик по шагам. Выходит вот так. Сначала все хорошо, указателю pasp присваивается верное значение, но уже через строчку значение произвольно меняется. Проблему найти не могу. Вот картинка для пояснения: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[С тяжким вздохом, монотонно]*

Возврат указателя на локальную переменную, которая при выходе из функции уничтожается... Undefined behaviour, то бишь неопределенное поведение.

Добавим сюда утечку памяти:

```
char* pasp = new char;
pasp= GetPasport();
```

Ну и последнее - отключенные предупреждения компилятора, потому что при включенных он обо всем этом (ну, кроме утечки памяти) должен предупреждать...

Если ну очень хочется именно так - объявите `pasp` как `static`:

```
static char pasp[12];
```

Это увеличит время ее существования до всего времени работы программы.

Comment: спасибо, то есть моя ошибка в том, что я возвращаю указатель на переменную, которая при выходе из функции уничтожается. Тогда вопрос, вот вы написали через static, а как сделать более правильно?

Comment: можно передать в функцию в качестве аргумента ваш указатель который в main()

Comment: Я бы - раз у вас С++ - работал через `string`, каковой бы и возвращал.

Comment: @Harry благодарю, я бы тоже через string сделал это и не мучался, но в задании в лабораторной работе именно указано создать массив char определенной длины.

Comment: @ТарасПрогер не совсем уверен, что понял вас, то есть я создаю указатель в main, и в функцию его передаю , как аргумент, функция же изменяет значение и возвращает мне тот же самый указатель с изменнным значением?

Comment: @Iskander смотрите ответ

Comment: Тогда вот несколько вариантов: 1. статический массив (как я предложил). 2. Передавать готовый массив в функцию в качестве аргумента. 3. Выделять массив динамически, через `new` (только потом не забывать его освобождать). Выбирайте сами, что больше подходит для вашей задачи...

Answer (score 1):

У вас битый(висящий) указатель.  Переместите `char pasp[12];` в глобальную область или прибавьте к массиву `static`, таким образом Вы продлите время жизни(2 вариант предпочтительней). Также не забывайте про `delete[]`.